# I cant edit my app description

Tags: app-store-connect

I cant edit my app description in iTunes after submitting the app. It was showing a LOCK SYMBOL in the description place which is not editable. I have a small spelling mistakes. Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 4):

App descriptions are no longer editable once an app has been submitted. They used to be, but this changed with the latest updates to the App Store. You'll only be able to edit the description when you submit a new version of the app.

You can find more information about what fields you can edit here:

https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/devfc3066644